# TextMagnifier in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-magnifier

Are there any packages available in flutter to implement TextMagnifier?

I need to magnify the text while editing the text by using TextFormField (like in the iphone).

Comment: maybe this is useful: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextMagnifier-class.html

Comment: This class still not available in flutter stable channel latest sdk. I am using flutter stable channel verison 3.3.10

Answer (score 3):

You can use magnifierConfiguration property in your TextField

Flutter has added support for text magnification from its 3.7 Release

You can refer this example below:

```js
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp(text: 'Hello world!'));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({
    super.key,
    this.textDirection = TextDirection.ltr,
    required this.text,
  });

  final TextDirection textDirection;
  final String text;

  static const Size loupeSize = Size(200, 200);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 48.0),
          child: Center(
            child: TextField(
              textDirection: textDirection,
              // Create a custom magnifier configuration that
              // this `TextField` will use to build a magnifier with.
              magnifierConfiguration: TextMagnifierConfiguration(
                magnifierBuilder:
                    (_, __, ValueNotifier<MagnifierInfo> magnifierInfo) =>
                        CustomMagnifier(
                  magnifierInfo: magnifierInfo,
                ),
              ),
              controller: TextEditingController(text: text),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomMagnifier extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomMagnifier({super.key, required this.magnifierInfo});

  static const Size magnifierSize = Size(200, 200);

  // This magnifier will consume some text data and position itself
  // based on the info in the magnifier.
  final ValueNotifier<MagnifierInfo> magnifierInfo;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Use a value listenable builder because we want to rebuild
    // every time the text selection info changes.
    // `CustomMagnifier` could also be a `StatefulWidget` and call `setState`
    // when `magnifierInfo` updates. This would be useful for more complex
    // positioning cases.
    return ValueListenableBuilder<MagnifierInfo>(
        valueListenable: magnifierInfo,
        builder: (BuildContext context, MagnifierInfo currentMagnifierInfo, _) {
          // We want to position the magnifier at the global position of the gesture.
          Offset magnifierPosition = currentMagnifierInfo.globalGesturePosition;

          // You may use the `MagnifierInfo` however you'd like:
          // In this case, we make sure the magnifier never goes out of the current line bounds.
          magnifierPosition = Offset(
            clampDouble(
              magnifierPosition.dx,
              currentMagnifierInfo.currentLineBoundaries.left,
              currentMagnifierInfo.currentLineBoundaries.right,
            ),
            clampDouble(
              magnifierPosition.dy,
              currentMagnifierInfo.currentLineBoundaries.top,
              currentMagnifierInfo.currentLineBoundaries.bottom,
            ),
          );

          // Finally, align the magnifier to the bottom center. The inital anchor is
          // the top left, so subtract bottom center alignment.
          magnifierPosition -= Alignment.bottomCenter.alongSize(magnifierSize);

          return Positioned(
            left: magnifierPosition.dx,
            top: magnifierPosition.dy,
            child: RawMagnifier(
              magnificationScale: 2,
              // The focal point starts at the center of the magnifier.
              // We probably want to point below the magnifier, so
              // offset the focal point by half the magnifier height.
              focalPointOffset: Offset(0, magnifierSize.height / 2),
              // Decorate it however we'd like!
              decoration: const MagnifierDecoration(
                shape: StarBorder(
                  side: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    width: 2,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              size: magnifierSize,
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```